# There is no "Connector: Analog Line-In" on the INPUT tab of Sound Preferences -- Why NOT?

Tags: sound-blaster

I connected an analog tape deck to my Soundblaster Audigy Analog Line-In input. I have a 2 to 1 cable connecting the Tape-OUT to the Audigy-LINE-IN.

I can't hear any sound when the Tape Deck plays. I have no problem when on Windows.

How do I get the tape deck to play on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend installing alsamixer it will grab those settings from your PCM card and you can modify the settings as you wish.

Installing

Install with Command Line

Adding the ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the linux-alsa-driver-modules package

```
sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)
```

Note: After installing the linux-alsa-driver-modules package, your system needs to be rebooted.

[image]

If you need other information or troubleshooting refer to:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting